# Issue redirecting stdout to file on Windows in a Python 3.6 subprocess

Tags: python, windows

Given a text file that contains the string 'something' somewhere this code works on Linux/MacOs (in the sense that the subprocess creates a new file with the lines from the first file containing the string 'something') but the redirection does not work on Windows (Python 3.6) - the new file is created but is empty:

```
if os.name == "nt":
    script = 'findstr /r something some_file > some_dir/some_file'
    script_name = 'wat.bat'
    with open(script_name, 'w') as f:
         f.write(script + '\n')
    p = subprocess.Popen(script_name, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
else:
    script = 'grep -E something some_file > some_dir/some_file'
    script = 'wat.sh'
    with open(script_name, 'w') as f:
         f.write(script + '\n')
    p = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sh", script_name], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

The docs explain some Windows specifics [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) but I think it could be more lucid.

So in short, I hope what I want to do is clear enough and I would be very grateful for any advice.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, your isolated code snippets appear a bit unclear…

Comment: I have since learned eg [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output?redirectedfrom=MSDN)  that on Windows redirection in a spawned process requires special handling of the handles. Alas I have still not understood how to get this working using Python. So the essence of the question is: on Windows, what do I do to make redirection of stdout to a file work in a subprocess in Python?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Redirection runs smoothly for me (with necessary `import`s). Redirection must run for you as well because  *the new file is created*. In any case, I'd change path separator to ```\\``` as ```script = r'findstr /r something some_file > some_dir\some_file'```, and add `, shell=True` to `subprocess.Popen` - although the docs says explicitly *You do not need `shell=True` to run a batch file or console-based executable*…

Comment: Thanks! And I was deep in the ju-ju with file handles from ctypes and watnot and missed the path spec on the redirect command. Now all is well.